# Print arabic characters using logstash exec plugin

Tags: python, twitter, logstash, tweepy

I created a python script which gathers tweets using “Tweepy”. Then, I returned each tweet in a certain dict format. My tweets may contain arabic and latin characters.

This is my python script:

```
import tweepy
import json

credentials = {
    "consumer_key": "4qpWxxx",
    "consumer_secret": "maHAYxxx",
    "access_key": "9260767xxx",
    "access_secret": "FYlz7Rxxx"}

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(credentials["consumer_key"], credentials["consumer_secret"])
auth.set_access_token(credentials["access_key"], credentials["access_secret"])

############ Tweepy version 4.10.0 ############
from datetime import date
today = date.today()
since = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

api = tweepy.API(auth, 
                 retry_count=10,
                 timeout=300)

search = tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,
                       q=["الجزائر"],
                       count=maxTweets,
                       tweet_mode = "extended",
                       result_type="mixed",                     
                       since="2022-07-21",
                       include_entities=True
                       )
val=  []
for tweet in search.items(10):
    val.append(tweet)

Tweets =[]
for i in range(len(val)):    
    model={    
    "text": val[i].full_text,
    "id_str": val[i].id_str,
    "lang": val[i].lang    
    }    
    
    Tweets.append(model)    
    
resultat= {"results": Tweets}    
print(resultat)
```

Then , I gathered the returned value using the exec plugin of logstash like this:

```
input {
exec {
command => 'python python_twitter.py'
interval => 1000

}
}


output {
stdout {
codec => rubydebug
}
}
```

I have two issues with this solution:
1- tweepy prints automatically some messages 'exp: unexcepcted value since". I have to stop this printings.

2- I have a charset error when the tweet is in arabic. this error is returned by logstash

any help please.